# Laravel redirect to route from controller when called by AJAX

Tags: php, laravel

Given this chunk of `ajax` that calls `FriendsController@destroy`

```
$.ajax({
    url:     '/dashboard/friends/' + id,
    type:    'DELETE',
    data:    { src: 'show' },
    success: function(response) {
    }
});
```

How can I `return Redirect::route('dashboard.friends.index')` inside `FriendsController` after the delete procedure is completed? I guess this is trying to return the response back to AJAX which doesn't know how to react.

I could just `window.location.href = '/dashboard/friends'` but I want to Flash a success message to the view which I can't do with AJAX.

Comment: Why don't flash your success message in the success function, then wait 3 seconds before redirect with `window.location.href = '/dashboard/friends'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is how I solved this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30007568/1133306) on my own. For functions such as performing an AJAX delete of a model, it will prompt a confirmation modal, perform the delete, flash the message and redirect to the provided route.

Once setup it can be done dynamically by passing in the proper `data` attributes to the original delete button or link.

Answer (score 12):

I found the most easiest way of doing this.
just use same url again in your ajax success. assuming friends is your route name then

```
$.ajax({
    url:     '/dashboard/friends/' + id,
    type:    'DELETE',
    data:    { src: 'show' },
    success: function(response) {
       window.location.href = "friends";
    }
});
```

this way you can just put redirect or flash session message if you want.

Answer (score 3):

i know this might be old question but if you want to return a dynamic route

`return route('post.view', ['id' => $result]);`

and in your front-end you will do

```
  success: function(response){
          window.location.replace(response);
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem and here is what did the tricks for me.

In your controller, you can flash the message using:

`\Session::flash('success', __('locale.message'));`

And then in your ajax response handler, you redirect to wherever you want

`location.replace('/home');`

Don't forget to add the login in your view to display the message, I.E:

```
 @if (session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        {{ session('success') }}
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
 @endif
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
if(data.success){

    var loc = window.location;
    window.location = loc.protocol+"//"+loc.hostname+"/admin/dashboard";
}
```